# Denormalize to reduce the use of aggregate functions (calculations) such as COUNT and AVG: worth it?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, denormalization

I'm trying to add some optimizations to my listing queries. Some of them have 4+ joins (some OUTER JOINs), require aggregate functions (COUNT, AVG) with GROUP BY, and sometimes need to be sorted by these calculated values. I see that "temporary" and "filesort" are both used.

I do have caches for the initial queries, but I'm not planning on caching the "load more" ones. I worry that these queries may not scale well.

Now, I'm tempted to denormalize by added the calculated values to the main table.

Suppose we have currently, normalized:

```
SELECT p.id, p.product_name, p.time_created, COALESCE(AVG(r.rating),0) AS rating, COUNT(r.rating) AS review_count
FROM product AS p LEFT JOIN review AS r ON p.id = r.product_id 
GROUP BY p.id HAVING (rating, time_created) < (?, ?)
ORDER BY rating DESC, time_created DESC
LIMIT ?
```

Denormalized, it could be:

```
SELECT id, product_name, time_created, rating, review_count
FROM product WHERE (rating, time_created) < (?, ?)
ORDER BY rating DESC, time_created DESC
LIMIT ?
```

with an index on the two fields.

The denormalized one is certainly faster to read. But to write it's certainly slower. The question I have is: Is this worth it?

If I do it, should I

1. add a stored procedure to calculate the redundant fields when data is inserted,
2. add a scheduled event to calculate them,
   or
3. just let the program calculate it because speed is not important (though load on the DB could be)?

EDIT:

I implemented it and added a couple of triggers on the source to calculate the view each time it's changed. Read is maybe 40% faster (with 50 rows of test data, hopefully will scale better since a "temporary" table is not used). This may be the easiest way to implement it. Insert is slower. I keep both versions and will monitor with real data.

One of the triggers I added is something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER review_insert AFTER INSERT ON product_review FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE product AS p
SET p.rating = 
(SELECT COALESCE(AVG(r.rating),0) FROM product_review AS r WHERE r.product_id = p.id)
WHERE p.id = NEW.product_id;
```

(edited because WHERE was missing in the trigger)

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment.

If you have an operational system, you should keep the normalized tables.  These follow the normalization principle that any given data item is stored in one place.  And that makes them the right way to store the "master" copy of the data.

You seem to want restructured data for analysis.  For your simple example, a view should be fine.  But the general idea is that sometimes a different data structure is helpful for analysis.

I would recommend storing the analysis data in a different database, preferably on a different server.  In general, I would suggest have periodic (say daily) batch runs to update/replace the data.  These can be schedule when the master system is quiescent.  You *can* use triggers or similar constructs to keep the data up-to-date in real time.

Comment: Thanks. That's not for analysis but for serving data on the website (think of it as a list of products).